# Looping through Javascript Object and adding to HTML Div

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom, javascript-objects

I am working on a game and have run into a problem that I have been stuck on for hours. I have an object, and I want to write a loop which will take all the values in this object, and stick them into an html div. The way I am doing this is, I have taken a div, I am cloning it and giving all the child elements new values. Then I want to use the DOM manipulation to insert the values from one key, into a div with a heading and two paragraphs. Here is the code.

Index.html

```
<div id = "all_asset" style = "display: none;">
    <div class = "touch_box col-sm-12" style = "height: 150px; display: none;" id = "asset_touchbox">
        <br><h id = "asset_name"></h>
        <p1 id = "asset_price"></p1><hr>
        <p id = "asset_age"></p><hr>
    </div>    
</div>
```

play.js

```
function assetsList(){
    Object.keys(assets).forEach(key => {
        for (var i = 1; i < Object.keys(assets).length; i++){
    
            //duplicate box
            var list_box = document.getElementById("asset_touchbox");
            var clone_box = list_box.cloneNode(true);
            clone_box.id = "list_assets" + String(i);
            document.getElementById("all_asset").appendChild(clone_box);

            //get id of child elements
            clone_box.getElementsByTagName('h')[0].id = "asset_name" + String(i);
            clone_box.getElementsByTagName('p1')[0].id = "asset_price" + String(i);
            clone_box.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].id = "asset_age" + String(i);
            list_box.parentNode.appendChild(clone_box);
            //show box
            clone_box.style.display = "block";

            var asset_name = assets[key][0];
            var asset_age = assets[key][1];
            var asset_price = assets[key][2];

            document.getElementById("asset_name" + String(i)).innerHTML = asset_name;
            document.getElementById("asset_price" + String(i)).innerHTML = asset_age;
            document.getElementById("asset_age" + String(i)).innerHTML = asset_price;
        }
      });      
}
```

Javascript Object

```
//asset name, asset age, asset cost
assets = {1: ["Boat", 0, "10000"], 2: ["Carriage", 0, "10000"]}
```

So what I pretty much want to do is - Create two divs, each one has the information from each key. I hope I made sense. Please let me know if I didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd build the asset html inside your forEach function instead of cloning placeholder html. The code below should create the structure you're looking for. Good luck!

index.html

```
<div id="all_asset"/>
```

play.js

```
const assets = {
  1: ["Boat", 0, "10000"],
  2: ["Carriage", 0, "10000"]
}

function assetsList() {
  Object.keys(assets).forEach(key => {
    // get current asset data
    const assetData = assets[key];
    // create asset container
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    // create and append asset header
    const header = document.createElement('h1');
    header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(assetData[0]))
    // create and append first p
    const p1 = document.createElement('p')
    p1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(assetData[1]))
    // crreate and append second p
    const p2 = document.createElement('p')
    p2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(assetData[2]))
    // fill out the asset container
    container.appendChild(header)
    container.appendChild(p1)
    container.appendChild(p2)
    // append the whole thing to the parent
    document.getElementById("all_asset").appendChild(container);
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `class` to simplify the code.

- [Classes - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

**Here is an example:**

```js
// The original object given by you
const givenAssets = {
  1: ['Boat', 0, '10000'],
  2: ['Carriage', 2, '30000']
};

// Get #all_asset
const assetContainer = document.querySelector('#all_asset');

// Define a class
class Asset {
  // Set parameters
  constructor(id, name, price, age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.age = age;
  }

  // Create HTML
  addHtml() {
    // HTML elements as string
    let html = `
      <div class="touch_box col-sm-12" id="list_asset${this.id}">
        <br>
        <h4 id="asset_name${this.id}">${this.name}</h4>
        <p id="asset_price${this.id}">${this.price}</p>
        <hr>
        <p id="asset_age${this.id}">${this.age}</p>
        <hr>
      </div>`;
      
    // Add HTML element before the end of #all_asset
    assetContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  }
}

// Make instances and put them into an array
let assets = [];
for (const key in givenAssets) {
  assets.push(new Asset(key, givenAssets[key][0], givenAssets[key][1], givenAssets[key][2]))
}

// Execute .addHtml() on each asset one by one.
assets.forEach(asset => asset.addHtml());
```

```html
<div id="all_asset"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't use your original object `assets = {1: ["Boat", 0, "10000"], 2: ["Carriage", 0, "10000"]}`. If you want to use it, let me know. Then I'll modify my code.

Comment: Yes, actually. That would be really great.

Comment: I did it. Check it please ;)

Comment: I removed the `.replace()` part of `let html`. Values can be passed into the string directly because of template literal ``.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider refactoring your representation of the assets as an array of objects.  For example,

```js
let assets = [
  {
    name: 'boat',
    age: 0,
    price: 10000,
  },
  {
    name: 'carriage',
    age: 0,
    price: 10000,
  },
];
```

Following your initial idea of using the `forEach` method to iterate over the assets, you could dynamically insert a div for every asset.

```js
assets.forEach(({ name, age, price }) => {
  let touchBox = document.createElement('div');
  touchBox.classList.add('touch_box', 'col-sm-12');
  touchBox.id = 'asset_touchbox';
  touchBox.style.height = '150px';

  let nameElt = document.createElement('h5');
  nameElt.id = 'asset_name';
  nameElt.innerHTML = name;

  let priceElt = document.createElement('p');
  priceElt.id = 'asset_price';
  priceElt.innerHTML = price;

  let ageElt = document.createElement('p');
  ageElt.id = 'asset_age';
  ageElt.innerHTML = age;

  touchBox.appendChild(nameElt);
  touchBox.appendChild(priceElt);
  touchBox.appendChild(ageElt);

  document.querySelector('#list_box').appendChild(touchBox);
});
```